# Actionscript/ Wikipedia API

Tags: actionscript, wikipedia

I'm working on Actionscript project , I need to call Wikipedia API's , but Wikipedia doesn't contain CrossDomain.xml file to enable flash access.

any suggestion !

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

If your project is a web page and you have control over the html source, you could simply proxy the calls via ExternalInterface to JavaScript. If you also have control over your server, you can write a very simple php script to relay your commands to wikipedia.

However, if you are on a web page but don't have control over the JS part, don't fret: Turns out you DO have full control by injecting whatever JS you like:

```
// initially: call anonymous function writing a named function into global JS space
// you could more or less inject a complete framework here. Or a simple JS http proxy.
ExternalInterface.call('function(){hello = function(foo){alert(foo);};}()');
// somewhere else in your code
ExternalInterface.call('hello("world")');
```

Isn't it fun how you can work around a completely useless security measure (cossdomain.xml) by abusing a critical security problem (javascript injection)?
:)